# how to get model name that has m2m relation to a specific model

Tags: django-models

Suppose I have two models A and B:

class A(models.Model):

```
 name = models.CharField()
```

class B(models.Model):

```
 field = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

How can I get the model name B and field from string A? or how can I get model name A and field from string B? Either is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
B._meta.get_field('field').related_model._meta.model_name
```